# Sending post data using curl and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, proxy, cross-domain

I am trying to send a post data using a proxy script to perform cross-domain ajax.

```
var data = "url=http://www.fhm.com.ph/templates/100sexiestwomen2013/ajax/set.php&id=13&index=0&action=add";
$.ajax({
    url: "proxy.php",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('Success ' + data);

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Then I tried to parse the data to use as the url and parameters in my proxy script.

```
<?php
    //set POST variables
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    unset($_POST['url']);
    $fields_string = "";
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

But it turns out it doesn't post the data correctly.

Try using postman, a chrome extension [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en). And give the proper key-value pairs as seen in the `data`.

It'll give you `null` on first submit and `selected` on second.

What am I missing out.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
    //set POST variables
    $url = $_POST['url'];
//    unset($_POST['url']);
//    $fields_string = "";
//    //url-ify the data for the POST
//    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
//            $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
//    }
//    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

As shown in the edit, i remove my manual build, instead I used the POST array.

Answer (score 2):

Use an object in your Javascript for the `data`, so that jQuery will encode it properly:

```
var data = {
   url: "http://www.fhm.com.ph/templates/100sexiestwomen2013/ajax/set.php&id=13",
   index: 0,
   action: "add"
};
```

And in the PHP, use an array for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$_POST);
```

PHP will encode this properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to properly encode your data

```
var data = "url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://www.fhm.com.ph/templates/100sexiestwomen2013/ajax/set.php")+"&id=13&index=0&action=add";
```

Since you url parameter contains characters that has special meaning in urls.

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito okay I now see what going on, I thought it was just one parameter.

Comment: i think it still doesn't work, you may try it too, maybe I'll fiddle it, wanna fiddle it too?

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito try setting `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$_POST);` with `$_POST` instead of manually trying to build the post body.

Comment: i'll post your suggestion, but it seem that it doesn't work too.